# How do I add "" to header row items in DictWrite at Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to write a method that passes a list of dictionaries to a csv file.

I have the following list:

```
List = [{'a': 10, 'e': 14, 'b': 11, 'd': 13, 'c': 12}, {'a': 20, 'e': 24, 'b': 
21, 'd': 23, 'c': 22}, {'a': 30, 'e': 34, 'b': 31, 'd': 33, 'c': 32}, {'a': 
40, 'e': 44, 'b': 41, 'd': 43, 'c': 42}]
```

And the following code:

```
def ListDic_to_CSV(filename, table, fieldnames, separator, quote):

    with open(filename, "w", newline="") as csvfile:
            csvwrite=csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter =separator, quotechar = quote)
            csvwrite.writeheader()
            for row in table:
                csvwrite.writerow(row)
```

I'm trying to get:

```
"a","b","c","d","e"
10,11,12,13,14
20,21,22,23,24
30,31,32,33,34
40,41,42,43,44
```

But i get:

```
a,b,c,d,e
10,11,12,13,14
20,21,22,23,24
30,31,32,33,34
40,41,42,43,44
```

How do i change my code so that the fieldnames have "" around them?

Comment: Why do you need the quotes? Usually in CSV you only use quotes when the string contains the separator character, ie a comma.

Comment: it's an assignment i'm working on whose solutions are the ones with the quoted fields. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

You can force to have always `quotation marks` `"` by setting the **quoting** attribute of your writer to `csv.QUOTE_ALL` and your **quotechar** to `"`. However as `Daniel Roseman` already mentioned, the reason this attribute exists is to quote fields that contain separator characters like `,` or  or whichever you have selected.

Here is a little example that sets `quotechar` and `quoting`:

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar='"')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
```

**Output names.csv:**

```
"first_name","last_name"

"Baked","Beans"
```

**Header Only:**

If you are interested in just having the `headers` aka `fieldnames` to be written with `quotes` you can instead of using `writer.writeheader()` just do `writer.writerow()` and compose your own header. Basically, `writeheader` is nothing more than a convenient function that calls `writerow`with a dict.

```
import csv

with open('names3.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar=None)
    quotedFieldnames = [(name,'\"{0}\"'.format(name) ) for name in fieldnames]
    customHeader = dict(quotedFieldnames)
    writer.writerow(customHeader)
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
```

Comment: this solution quotes everything including the data items. Is there not a way to just quote the fieldnames row items?

Comment: Ah i see, is adding `\"fieldname\"` not an option?  You could overwrite the `writeHeader` method of `DictWriter` then you can define how your field names are constructed.

Comment: Just added an example where you pass the quoted fields.